# Is it possible to run html <script> in the flash banner?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript, flash

I'd like to run some javascript code directly "from the flash (swf) banner".

Is it possible? And how can I manage that?

Comment: So, you want a communication layer between ActionScript and JavaScript so that you can call a certain JavaScript function from the ActionScript part of a flash banner ?

Comment: I have already found some information about calling js functions from the ActionScript, but I need exactly to run a script. Not a function.

Comment: Are you trying to inject a script into a page or call a function that is already present within the loaded JavaScript of the page?

Comment: I'm exactly trying to inject a script into a page. I do not want to call function, which is already loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can add an entirely new script tag.  Why are you trying to add a new tag?  What functionality is available through JS that is not already present through ActionScript?  Also, are you planning on running this banner from your own domain?  You'll probably run into some domain access problems if you aren't.  Consider: [Run JS from Flash](http://www.akchauhan.com/how-call-javascript-function-from-flash/) and [Calling JS from SWF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/884708/691711)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to inject JS scripts in the DOM using ActionScript and then communicate via the injected functions you could do something like this:

1) import the external class.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
```

2) declare a constant variable with all the JS functions:

```
private const script_js :XML =
<script>
<![CDATA[
function() {
  AJXFNC = {
    ajaxFunction:function(_url){
      var ajaxRequest;
      try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari, Chrome
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", _url, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
      } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
          ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          ajaxRequest.open("GET", _url, true);
          ajaxRequest.send();
        } catch (e) {
          try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", _url, true);
            ajaxRequest.send();
          } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
]]>
</script>;
```

3) inject the JS to DOM:

```
try {
  if( ExternalInterface.available )ExternalInterface.call( script_js );
} catch( error:Error ) {
  trace("ExternalInterface is not available");
}
```

4) call a function:

```
ExternalInterface.call( "AJXFNC.ajaxFunction", "http://www.google.com" );
```

I have pasted the technique into this answer because i usually do not trust the up-time of a blog, but all rights go to Adi Feiwel, for writing this: http://todepoint.com/blog/2011/08/01/injecting-and-calling-js-functions-from-within-flash-using-external/